# In tic tac toe game the computer is able to put their "piece" on top of the players

Tags: python

The problem is in the select_spot function. When the player places their piece on the board sometimes the computer will write their piece on top of the players. I am not sure how to re-write the conditionals to stop this from happening.

```
def select_spot(self):
    global computer_piece
    
    computer_row = random.randint(0,2)
    computer_column = random.randint(0,2)   
    row = int(input('Enter your preferred row: '))
    column = int(input('Enter your preferred column: '))
    
    if self.board[row][column] != player and self.board[row][column] == '-' :
        self.board[computer_row][computer_column] = computer_piece
    if row >= 0 and row <= 2 and self.board[row][column] == '-':
      self.board[row][column] = player
    if column >= 0 and column <= 2 and self.board[row][column] == '-':
      self.board[row][column] = player
    else:
      print('Error')
    return self.board
```

I have tried switching around the order of the conditionals. But none of them give me the result I want which is for the computer to place a piece on the board that is empty and does not contain the players piece. Would making a separate function for the computer's piece then putting that into the select spot function work? I have also tried using elif statements and which does not work as well.

Ignore this: I have tried switching around the order of the conditionals. But none of them give me the result I want which is for the computer to place a piece on the board that is empty and does not contain the players piece. Would making a separate function for the computer's piece then putting that into the select spot function work? I have also tried using elif statements and which does not work as well.

Comment: The first `if` checks in the condition if the field chosen by **user** is empty and if so, occupies the field chosen (randomly) by **computer** for the computer, regardless if it was occupied by the player already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only place the computer_piece after checking if the spot is not occupied by a player_piece. Right now you're considering only the users input when placing the computer_piece. So when you have for example computer_row = 2, computer_column = 2, row = 1 and column = 1, you check in the first if-Condition, whether board[1][1] is already occupied by a player_piece, but if not you set board[2][2] to a computer_piece, which could be occupied or not. I adjusted your code a littl

```
computer_column = random.randint(0,2)   
row = int(input('Enter your preferred row: '))
column = int(input('Enter your preferred column: '))


if self.board[computer_row][computer_column] != player and self.board[computer_row][computer_column] == '-' :
    self.board[computer_row][computer_column] = computer_piece
if row >= 0 and row <= 2 and self.board[row][column] == '-':
  self.board[row][column] = player
else:
  print('Error')
return self.board
```